# Is it good style to hide shared_ptr behind a typedef?

Tags: c++

I'd like to reduce some visual noise in the code and hide `shared_ptr` behind a typedef like this:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<SomeLongClass> SomeLongClassPtr;
```

So this:

```
void foo(const boost::shared_ptr<SomeLongClass>& a,
         boost::shared_ptr<SomeLongClass>& b);
```

becomes this:

```
void foo(const SomeLongClassPtr& a, SomeLongClassPtr& b);
```

On the other hand I'm worried that I'm reducing the explicitness of the code.

Which is a better style?

Comment: This is sort of a duplicate of [What's your convention for typedefing shared_ptr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717436/whats-your-convention-for-typedefing-shared-ptr)

Comment: @James, thanks, I failed to find this question myself.

Comment: PleaseUseUnderScoresInsteadOfCapitalizingTheFirstLettersBecauseThisIsHardToRead

Comment: @Inverse: You have joined the Style Holy Wars. A war that will never be won by any side and will go on for eternity, or as long as we have human programmers... and even then who knows. I imagine even the robots will fight about it. :-)

Comment: @JustBoo Sure, I remember that movie with Arnold S. where he was sent back in time to kill the leader of the underscore resistance.

Comment: @Tom, I am literally laughing out loud. Nice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given that std::string is itself a typedef, I think you are fine. I do it myself.

Even Scott Meyers recommends typedef for ease of reading code in cases like yours.

---

EDIT: 
Effective C++, Second Edition, Page 120, Item 28, fourth paragraph. "...provide typedefs that remove the need..."

More Effective C++, 7th printing, Page 237, Item 31 First paragraph.

More Effective C++, 7th printing, Page 238, Item 31 First paragraph after code sample.

---

In essence, no worries. :-)

Comment: I'd love to have a Scott Meyers' reference to that, but meanwhile I'll take your word for it.

Answer (score 9):

We use `TypePtr` typedefs in our code for `shared_ptr<Type>` objects.  It is also useful to have a `TypeConstPtr` for `shared_ptr<const Type>`.

Comment: Ditto. If it improves readability and maintainability, it can hardly be a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm kind of opposed to typedefs that hide whether things are real pointers (or references), having seen too much unreadable C code that does this. But applying some casuistry, I guess shared_ptrs are not real pointers, and so the typedef is OK. But you are losing information - you can no longer tell just by looking at the function declaration (or definition!) what its semantics are.

Comment: And let me guess, you are absolutely opposed to putting a "p" in front of it. That would smack of Hungarian Notation and we certainly can’t have any of that! I favor pragmatism over the herd mentality. And no, I don't use or condone HN. I will put a "p" in front of a pointer name on occasion though.

Comment: @JustBoo I've never been accused of following the herd before, but I suppose there is  a first time for everything. And I do use a very limited for of Hungarian myself - all my member variables are prefixed with an 'm'.

Comment: @Neil: Well alright then. :-D I do too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461697/cstring-variable-name-prefix/3461766#3461766 coupled with the occasional "p" and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You might name the typedef 'SomeLongClassSharedPtr', which is both explicit and easy to type.

A negative consequence from this practice is that some autocomplete implementations (e.g. in Eclipse CDT) fail to follow through it. That hasn't stopped me personally from using it though.